# What does it mean for a root to be an element of the Lie algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

My understanding of roots in Lie algebra theory is as follows: given a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}\subset\mathfrak{g}$ with basis $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{r}$, and root vectors $\{X_\alpha\}_\alpha$, the roots $\alpha$ are $r$-dimensional vectors in Euclidean space such that

$$ [H_i, X_\alpha] = \alpha_i X_\alpha \quad \forall 1\leq i \leq r.$$

I am currently reading Bryan Hall's *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representation Theory*, and here, roots $\alpha$ are defined as linear functionals such that, for all $H \in \mathfrak{h}$
$$[H, X_\alpha] = \langle \alpha, H\rangle X_\alpha.$$
This makes sense to me, as, if one writes
$$H = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \lambda_i H_i,$$
then presumably this linear functional is defined as
$$ \langle \alpha, H\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \lambda_i \langle \alpha, H_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \lambda_i \alpha_i.$$
My confusion is: throughout the text, the roots are specified as elements of the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$. I don't understand how this is the case. At best, I could see that the roots are actually elements of the dual of the Cartan subalgebra, since they are linear functionals acting on $\mathfrak{h}$. Could someone clarify what is meant when they say that roots $\alpha$ are elements of $\mathfrak{h}$, and, given a root, how do I express the root as a linear combination of the basis elements of $\mathfrak{h}$?

Comment: If your $\langle,\rangle$ is the restriction of the Killing form to $\mathfrak h$, then it gives an identification of $\mathfrak h$ with its own dual. Roots can be defined without this, as you say, simply as elements of the dual of $\mathfrak h$. They are the simultaneous eigenvalues by which $\mathfrak h$ acts (by adjoint) on the whole $\mathfrak g$.